# Google maps setCenter using marker is not working properly as its is showing the market at left-top instead of center

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google maps setCenter using marker is not working properly as its is showing the market at left-top instead of center. Following is the code that i have used :

```
<body id="ViewMapScreen">
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 349px;"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var address = 'Pune, Maharastra, India';

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       zoom: 8
   });   

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   },
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
   });   

   </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Are you displaying the map in a hidden div?

Comment: Actually i'm using it in an application where it'll come as a pop up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the width and height of the div, then it will works fine.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 1270px; height: 850px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem has been solved. I uesd i-frame and there i called the same.